# Launching app from mobile website can open page twice

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, mobile-web

I just discovered the new `Read this post in our app` banner.

When clicking on a question it opens the app. When opening another question it puts it on top of the previous one. This seems all to make sense to me.

When opening the same question twice, it shows the second one on top of the first one. This seems unnecessary to me.

Please make sure that if a question is put on top, it isn't the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be implemented in the next build.

Right now I'm using two rules:

1. The question must be the top view at the time you tap the link.  If you go from Safari, to a question to a user profile, back to Safari and tap the link again, it'll put a new question on the stack.  I tried popping back to the question but it doesn't feel right removing things from the stack.
2. This only works for exact matches.  That is if you go from `/questions/255820` to the app, back to Safari, then to `/questions/255820/.../255981`, then to the app, it will open new question even though it could just scroll there.  The scrolling stuff if full of caveats that I don't want to deal with at this point.